# TableRow with image and 2 TextView

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I`m having problems for do something like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/examplehm.png/

My xml code shows 3 columns in the row but i want 2 columns and the second column must be divided in two horizontal parts.

My .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TableRow>        
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagen"        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingLeft="2dip" 
            android:paddingRight="5dip" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/cabecera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12px" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/descripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="10px" />           
    </TableRow>                         

</TableLayout>
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [Android Tricks #1 blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) - it'll show you two ways of doing it: one good and one... well, less good. :)

Comment: Thanks @MH. I did the 2 ways of the guide shows but my result is no good: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/137/listanofunciona1.png/ Maybe I must divide the xml in two files one of them with the ListView and the other with the rest of code... In the link you can see only one of the three results of the DB query. The row that shows only contains an image and one of the two texts. This happens when I try with RelativeLayout example of the guide, when I try with the first example my app don't shows rows :(

Comment: @MH. I saw that the second way of the guide works!!! but shows the 3 rows in a little space. I pulled the first row that you can see in the link and... surprise! the other two rows were there. Now my problem is how to do bigger the space to show all DB query results and show a third text. I still working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `LinearLayout` by the image and then put in it two `TextViews` , or use `RelativeLayout` for entire row.

Here is example of the first solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow>        
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagen"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="2dip" 
        android:paddingRight="5dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/cabecera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12px" 
            android:text="TextView"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/descripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="10px"
            android:text="TextView" />    
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer @vtuhtan but I still having problems. Following your second way answer, the app only shows the first row and his content still showing an imaget at left and in the next column one text. The third text appears nowhere. I didn't understand your first answer way.

Comment: Thanks @vtuhtan , I will try it later but I have a question for you in reference to your example code. In your opinion, I must have ListView and other presentation code in the same xml or would be better have them in separate files ?

Comment: Yeah, works perfectly! Thank you very much! I maintained the ListView in the same file. Thank guys! @MH